# ios Kill app problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm developing an iOS app with core data.

Every time I kill the app (by pressing the home button twice and kill)
then when I load the app again, the view is the same as before (maybe because it was restored successfully) but it's stuck without any error... if I press home button again then the screen becomes black and I can't see anything....

just the threads in Xcode and the status is "running"...

Anyone has an idea? or somewhere to start digging in?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you build and run from Xcode? If so what behavior you get, if you kill it from within Xcode (click the Stop button)?

Answer (score 1):

I know this problem. It is because of Xcode 4.  Here's the deal => Try running the App in the iPhone/iPad and you will not have that problem.

From my experience, the problem exists with the iPhone simulator and it works on the device !!

Comment: Wow is it so ? I had this problem twice. I just built it and ran it on my iPad. It ran like a champion. Anyways... Keep me posted if you find a solution. Thanks.